# ArgumentException in StreamWriter in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am writing a Xamarin.Form PLC for Android and iOS, and have a place where I need to write some application stuff to a text file embedded resource. I've implemented reading from the same text file successfully, with same syntax just using StreamReader, but the StreamWriter implementation looks like this:

```
                Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                string resource = "jetStream.Results.settings.txt";
                using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource)) {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
                       //do stuff
                    }
                }
```

StreamWriter is throwing an argument of "Stream is not writeable" at System.IO.StreamWriter. Am I doing something obvsiously wrong? Why is the Stream Readable but not Writeable using the same assembly/resource/stream construction?

Comment: You are trying to write to a resource inside of your app's package.  The package is signed and not writable (this is true on iOS also).  If you want to write to a file you need to select a writable folder that is not part of the package structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stream from `GetManifestResourceStream` is not writable. The stream's file is embedded in the assembly at build time and cannot be changed. You'll have to write the file to disk before you can write to it.

```
string resource = "jetStream.Results.settings.txt";
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    rStream.Stream.CopyTo(stream);
    writer.Write(stream.ToArray());
}
```

After this you can read and write to the file on disk.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to write, if it's just things like application settings, you can use the Application.Properties collection http://www.kymphillpotts.com/exploring-xamarin-forms-1-3-properties-dictionary/ otherwise I agree with Jon's answer.

Comment: Did not know about Application.Properties, this looks like it'll be super useful! In the case I was asking about, this is the perfect answer! (upvote). Giving Jon the green checkmark since I'll be needing to write more than just application settings to disk at some point, though I would like to give you both the accepted answer.